# How to fix Azure Portal not deploying a VM from image due to “No Plan” error

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy a VM from a custom image on Azure. I'm using the portal.[Portal VM Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWBGh.png)

When I create a VM from a product in the marketplace, everything goes smoothly. When I capture an image of the VM (going through the deallocation and generalizing process), and then try to deploy a VM from that image, it fails while creating the VM due to a "no plan" error.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL1Xb.png)

I've been troubleshooting and it seems I need a template and parameters json file to specify how to deploy, but the documentation on this is scarce and I'm unsure how to configure these files and what part of them is the "plan". I can take an existing VM/resource group and download the template.json and parameter.json files, but trying to create a new VM with these files fails.

Does anyone have experience with this or knows where adequate documentation is?

Comment: Is my update helpful?

Comment: Maybe, I am unable to verify until next week. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Azure Powershell, you could use the [Set-AzureRmVMPlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmplan?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [Set-AzVMPlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmplan?view=azps-1.7.0) cmdlet sets the Azure Marketplace plan information for a virtual machine. If you are using ARM template, you could refer to [Microsoft.Compute virtualMachines template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2019-03-01/virtualmachines).

```
 "plan": {
    "name": "string",
    "publisher": "string",
    "product": "string",
    "promotionCode": "string"
  },
```

> A Marketplace image in Azure has the following attributes:
>
> - Publisher: The organization that created the image. Examples: Canonical, MicrosoftWindowsServer
> - Offer: The name of a group of related images created by a publisher. Examples: UbuntuServer, WindowsServer
> - SKU: An instance of an offer, such as a major release of a distribution. Examples: 18.04-LTS, 2019-Datacenter
> - Version: The version number of an image SKU.

For more information about how to find image information, see Navigating and Selecting Azure Virtual Machine images with PowerShell and the Azure CLI in the Microsoft Azure documentation. You could use `az vm image list --output table` to [see a list of popular VM images in the Azure Marketplace with the Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/resource-groups-vm-searching/)

### Update

When I deploy a Xeams on Ubuntu in the marketplace, then [capture VM image from the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image#step-2-create-vm-image). I can reproduce this `no plan` issue when I directly create VM from this Image via the Azure portal. You could create a VM associated with the plan info via Azure CLI.

1. Find the plan info from the original VM(which was used for capturing custom Image)---`Export template`. Copy the plan info.

[image]

2. Then you could [create a VM from the captured image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image#step-3-create-a-vm-from-the-captured-image) associated with the plan info. 
   For example, this works on my side.

`az vm create --name vmname --location westus --image Imagename --admin-username username --admin-password userpassword  --plan-name xeams-ubuntu --plan-product xeams-ubuntu --plan-publisher apps-4-rent -g resourcegroup`

Result:

[image]

**Note**: You can create VMs from an image in any resource group within your subscription. To create a VM in a different resource group than the image, specify the full `resource ID` to your image. Also, you could create VMs in the same region as the Image.

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks for answering. I've learned a little more since running into this. The "plan" information is only needed when deploying a marketplace solution, so since I'm deploying from a custom image I don't need it. However since I built my custom image on a marketplace solution, the template still has the marketplace solution as my base, and so it thinks I need a plan. 

I'm currently trying to build a custom ARM template to deploy my image.

Comment: If you have a managed image in Azure portal, you could create VM from that custom image via easy ways like portal or PowerShell. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed). If your custom image existed in an existing storage account with a.VHD file, you can refer to this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-custom-image-new-storage-account) and modify some partition depends on your scenario to create a new VM from a custom image.

Comment: I have actually found those resources already. The portal does not work as described, and the templates are a massive undertaking. I'm trying to see if there is an easier way to do this than build a template from the ground up. For example, AWS created VMs from AMIs with a few button presses.

Comment: `The portal does not work as described`, could you share some picture or description about this, I can not imagine what happens on your side? So actually you want to know how to create a VM from the custom image via the portal instead of the template?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to use the portal. My end goal is to create a VM from a custom image; I don't care how I do that.

Comment: When I have an image in my resource group, I can select it and choose to "create VM". When the portal tries to do that, it fails due to a "no plan" error. If I download the creation template and parameters file instead and use the CLI to create the VM, it fails for the same reason. The templates seem to be filling in with information from the marketplace OS I built my application on, and the VM creation process gets confused and creates a bad template.

Comment: I added screenshots in my original post.

Comment: THAT WORKED!!! Thank you, this problem has been plaguing me for weeks.

Before when I tried to update the plan information in the template, the deployment would either pull from the marketplace and not use my image or give me an "The property 'imageReference.id' cannot be used together with property 'imageReference.publisher'" error. Do you know why your method is different?

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2570#issuecomment-187995133): create a VM from different ways with the template, especially `storageProfile` definition.

Comment: This is like substandard version of Microsoft Azure when it comes to BYOS. If one picks a "Pay As You Go" image from Microsoft, it doesn't ask any of this information. 
For BYOS, I really don't understand this unnecessary bureaucracy